# Why the motion of rotating magnet doesn't stop if we use a superconducting wire?

Tags: electromagnetism

I would like to know why magnets rotated,wouldn't stop their motion if we place a superconducting wire as said by [William Beaty](http://amasci.com/me.html) at [MadSci Network](http://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/1998-05/894171281.Eg.r.html).

Comment: Magnets would stop, it's just a nice bedtime story that superconductivity reduces "friction" to zero.

Comment: @CuriousOne:Could you tell then why [William](http://amasci.com/me.html) says that magnets _wouldn't_ stop if we use superconducting wires.

Comment: I don't know why some people like to tell physics bedtime stories. You will have to ask him yourself. Most of the time people probably think that they are doing you a favor if they are oversimplifying a problem. I am not one of those people.